# How to compare start date and end date in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

The user may choose a start date and end date for holiday. But, a problem may occur if the user choose an **end date** smaller than the **start date.**

```
        Start Date :  
        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="startDate" id="from" required/>
        End Date : 
        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="endDate" id="to" required/>
        <br>

        <input type ="hidden" name="empID" value="<%=empID%>">
        <input type="hidden" name="activity" value="mobilityType"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="status" value="pending"/>
        <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Submit"> 
        <input class="btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-block" type="reset" value="Reset">
```

A code to alert the user, if the user select an **end date** smaller than **start date** should be like:

```
  var from = $("#from").val();
  var to = $("#to").val();

  if(Date.parse(from) > Date.parse(to)){
      alert("Invalid Date Range");
  }else{
      alert("Valid date Range");
  }
```

Which should be the correct way to compare **start date** and **end date**?

Comment: What you have here should work as written. What more are you looking for?

Comment: So what is not working with what you tried. I assume that JavaScript code lives inside some function you call....

Comment: Firstly you need to properly parse the timestamps, `Date.parse(to)` is not a good way to do that, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)